# Unable to Navigate to new screen from within FlatList

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

My first page with `FlatList` is :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, FlatList, Text, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import MoreInfo from './MoreInfo';

export default class Page1 extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);       
    }


  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;   

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList
                data={users}
                renderItem={
                    ({item}) => 
                        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => navigate('MoreInfo', { name: 'Jane' })}>
                            <Text style={styles.welcome}> {item.name} </Text>
                        </TouchableHighlight>
                    }
                keyExtractor={item => item.index}
                >
            </FlatList>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

const App = StackNavigator({
    Page1: {screen: Page1},
    MoreInfo: { screen: MoreInfo },
})
```

I am able to get the data displayed in a `FlatList` without using the navigation. But when I put Navigation and click any item on the list, I get the error:

[image]

Please help. Trying this since 3 days.

My `index.android.js` is

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry} from 'react-native';

import MyApp2 from './src/components/MyApp2';

const MyApp2 = StackNavigator({
    Page1: {screen: Page1},
    MoreInfo: { screen: MoreInfo },
})

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp2', () => MyApp2);
```

And My `'./src/components/MyApp2'` is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, ScrollView, Alert,
        FlatList, ActivityIndicator, Image,TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

import { Container } from 'native-base';

import AppHeader from './AppHeader';
import AppBody from './AppBody';
import AppFooter from './AppFooter';


export default class MyApp2 extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <Container>
                <AppHeader />
                <AppBody/>
                <AppFooter />
            </Container>            
            )
    }
}
```

I further have some tabs in the `AppBody` and including `Page1` somewhere there. How would I go about it?

Comment: How are you registering your app? Since you're exporting `Page1` and not `App`, my hunch is that you're registering `Page1` in which case the app has no notion of navigation.

Comment: I did `Page1` for the `const Page1 = StackNavigator(` part and got `Duplicate declaration "Page1"` error. I am impoprting this page in another view so exporting `Page1`. The actual name of the app is `MyApp2`. I tried that too and got the same error as before.

Comment: No, you are misunderstanding. Your current `StackNavigator` code is fine. You need to export it probably and register that in your app. `react-navigation` should be the root of your app's entire structure. Post the part of your code with the rest of your navigators and the part with `AppRegistry.registerComponent`.

Comment: Ok. Understood. I updated my question and added the structure of my app. I have a nested kind of setup that is working fine, except for the navigation. Please help. Thanks for your time master.

Comment: Where exactly should I call for the Navigation ? Im trying multiple attempts and all failed.

Comment: So, what do you intend to be the entry point of your app? You're importing `MyApp2` and naming your `StackNavigator` the same thing - `MyApp2`. That's not quite right. Also, you're not importing `Page1` or `MoreInfo` in your index file so that needs to be fixed. I'll put together an example of what I think it should be but need to know the answer to the first question before I can do so.

Comment: I intend the entry point to be the imported `MyApp2`. And in there I'm importing the views for `AppHeader`, `AppBody` and `AppFooter`. And the `Page1` is imported to the `AppBody`. Is this wrong?

Comment: There are lot of mistakes in this code regarding the navigation part. I suggest you start from the scratch a new project and implement one by one. Check out the examples provided in react-navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're importing `Page1` anywhere and it's odd that you're importing `MyApp2` and then defining a `const` for the `StackNavigator` that is also called `MyApp2`. I cannot test this since there are other files being imported, but I believe you just need to:

- fix your imports,
- fix your naming conflicts,
- register all of your screens with StackNavigator so they all have access to the `navigation` prop,
- and register the `StackNavigator` for your `AppRegistry`.

Try this:

Leave **./src/components/MyApp2** as is. Then make these edits (I'll be making the assumption that `MyApp2`, `Page1`, and `MoreInfo` are all located in `./src/components/`:

**Page1** file (whatever that is named):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, FlatList, Text, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';

export default class Page1 extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);       
    }

  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;   

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList
                data={users}
                renderItem={
                    ({item}) => 
                        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => navigate('MoreInfo', { name: 'Jane' })}>
                            <Text style={styles.welcome}> {item.name} </Text>
                        </TouchableHighlight>
                    }
                keyExtractor={item => item.index}
                >
            </FlatList>
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**index.android.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

// Making an assumption for where these files are located
// since it's not in the original question.
import MyApp2 from './src/components/MyApp2';
import MoreInfo from './src/components/MoreInfo';
import Page1 from './src/components/Page1';

/**
 * This presumes that MyApp2 is the screen that will be loaded first.
 * I don't know how you are getting to Page1, but it will be accessible
 * if you navigate to it like so:
 *     this.props.navigation.navigate('Page1')
 * Once there, the navigate() in the FlatList of Page1 should work as written.
 */
const RootNavigator = StackNavigator({
    MyApp2: {screen: MyApp2},
    Page1: {screen: Page1},
    MoreInfo: { screen: MoreInfo },
})

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp2', () => RootNavigator);
```

Comment: Still fails with the same error. 'Undefined is not an object'. http://imgur.com/a/JoGdq

Comment: @Somename Completely forgot the `StackNavigator` import like YaSh Chaudhary says. Try it with that fix.

Comment: @Somename I'll have to look into it later when I'm not busy. My sandbox project that I use for answering questions literally has a screen that renders a `FlatList` with the same `renderItem` using `navigate` in the same way and it works fine. There's probably something that I'm missing.

Comment: created a new project from scratch and it's successful. I had to define all the navigation on the main index page and import all the routes. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In your **index.android.js** file , you are using `StackNavigator` but you have not imported it .

use :

`import { StackNavigator } from react-navigation`